# Checking if object is empty doesn't work

Tags: node.js, is-empty

I am testing the case if my **object** was **empty**, so intentionally I made a **query** that has no match in the database, which should evaluate my **else if** statement however I don't get any **response** in the **console**.

What am I doing wrong?

```
user.loginUser = (jUserData, res) => {
    var aData = [
        jUserData.email,
        jUserData.mobile_number,
        0
    ]
    var sQuery = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND mobile_number = ? AND active = ?'

    function isEmpty(obj) {
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    db.each(sQuery, aData, function (err, jRow) {
        console.log(jRow)
        if (err) {
            console.log('BAD, user not logged in')
            return res(true, {
                status: "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR"
            })
        }
        if (isEmpty(jRow)) {
            console.log('NOT FOUND')
            return res(true, {
                status: "NOT FOUND"
            })
        }
        console.log('GREAT, user logged in')
        return res(false, jRow)
        console.log(jRow)
    })
}
```

Comment: Does your `sQuery` return array when it is written correctly to return records?

Comment: this is how the result looks when query is written correctly:  `{ id: 50,
  first_name: 'j',
  last_name: 'j',
  email: 'j@gmail.com',
  mobile_number: 95659739,
  avatar: 'images/avatar-1525533262516.jpg',
  active: 1 }`

Answer (score 24):

You may like to use `Object.keys()` or other `Object` function, this code may help you

```
function isEmpty(obj) {
    return !obj || Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
}
```